# Why won't my WCF Data Service accept my querystring?

Tags: entity-framework, query-string, wcf-data-services

I'm using `jqGrid` to display some data to the user. One of the features needed is for users to be able to search the grid. I'm using a WCF Data Service to get this data and return it.

When I first started jqGrid development I just needed pagination (no searching required) and was successfully able to use the following method:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public String GetStuff(int? page, int? rows)
{ 
    // pagination going on in here
}
```

Then I needed the search so I added a param of type `string` like so:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public String GetStuff(int? page, int? rows, string search)
{ 
    // more stuff going on in here
}
```

and then I get a `400 Bad Request` error. I assume its because of the search param, I just don't understand why `int` works (and even `bool` worked) but `string` doesn't. Does it have anything to do with the fact that WCF Data Services are RESTful?

I of course double-checked the query string that jqGrid sends (via ajax) and it matches the param name. There are some extra query string params that jqGrid sends that are not used (ignoring them worked fine with my original pagination code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals in the query URL must be quoted with single quotes. So the above service operation would be called like this:
/GetStuff?page=1&rows=10&search='John'
Does your query string look like that?

Comment: No it didn't. I added the single-quotes and it works now, thanks!